Science fiction book with a character based on the emperor Claudius
It's possibly from the 60s or 70s and I think it was a novel and a sequel.
It's set in the future and a human society is recovering from a techno-crash. The main character is modeled on the emperor Claudius, in that he is brilliant but deformed and an unpopular hereditary ruler.
He is instrumental in recovering lost technology, and examples I remember are

assassins sent to his villa are turned to dust by the defensive walls of his villa
his enemies are disconcerted  by the multiple copies of a document that he produced with a photocopier
an important artifact is a silver ball that moves back and forth along a track and he discovers that it can act as a distant-viewer by inserting a microscope into it.

A second character is a large strong barbarian. In one scene the emperor is trying to force the second character to do something, I forget what, by repeatedly drowning and reviving him but he doesn't succeed. It's just possible that the barbarian had hidden the silver artifact and later says that if he had known what he knows now then he would have revealed the location.
A later part of the story, and it may be a sequel, is set in a different society, possibly a different planet. Aliens have arrived in a space-ship and the natives accept them as friendly but the emperor wishes to destroy the ship. He organises this by teleporting suicide-bombers up to the ship and the volunteers race to critical part of the ship in order to bring it down. They are dying as they race because the aliens only allow humans on the ship by invitation and the ship's environment is normally set to kill humans.
In the final scene I remember, the emperor and the barbarian are now friends and are strolling incognito when they come across a sculptor (or artist). The artist says he is dashing off a work to praise the emperor who has given himself the title of 'Saviour of Mankind' or something similarly grandiose. he asks if the pair would like to model raising their arms in praise to the emperor. The real emperor declines but the barbarian says he is willing.

Empire of the Atom by A. E. van Vogt.

It's a fixup of several short short stories so you may have read the individual stories. The character is called Clane and he is born deformed after his mother Lady Tania was exposed to radiation during pregnancy when she was staying next to a temple:

The agents of the Lord Leader discovered at the first investigation that one small area of the lead wall of the temple was radioactive. They were unable to determine the reason for the activity, because the wall at that point was of the required thickness. But the fact was what they reported to their master. Before midnight of the second day after the child was born, the decision was in the making.

The setting is based on the Roman Empire, though the city is Linn not Rome. It is set after some form of nuclear catastrophe, and the effects of radiation are attributed to the Atom Gods.
The assassination attempt is made by the widow of the recently dead Lord Emperor, Lydia, as part of a scheme to make her son Tews the next Lord Emperor. She sends the assassin Merle to kill Clane:

"Has there been any word yet from Meerl?"
"None, gracious lady."
She frowned over that. Her assassin had formed a relationship with her, which she had first accepted reluctantly, then, recognizing its value, with smiling grace. He had access to her bedroom at all hours of the day or night. And it was rather surprising that he to whom she had entrusted such an important errand, should not have reported long since.
Dalat was speaking again. "I think, madam, you should inform him, however, that it is unwise for him to have parcels delivered here addressed to himself in your care."
Lydia was climbing out of bed. She looked up, astounded and angry.
"Why, the insolent fool, has he done that? Let me see the parcel."
She tore off the wrapping, furiously. And found herself staring down at a vase filled with ashes. A note was tied around the lip of the vase. Puzzled, she turned it over and read:
Dear Madam:
Your assassin was too moist. The atom gods, once roused, become frantic in the presence of moisture.
Signed, Uranium
For the council of gods.

The defensive walls on Clane's villa are described a few pages later when Lydia sends a task force to kill Clane:

The morning was unnaturally hot. Blasts of warm air came sweeping down the hill from the direction of Clane's house. And, after a little, she saw that the soldiers one hundred yards up the hill, had stopped.
The pause grew long and puzzling, and she was just about to climb out of the chair, when she saw Maljan coming towards her. The dark-eyed, hawk-nosed officer was sweating visibly.
"Madam," he said, "we cannot get near that fence up there. It seems to be on fire."
"I can see no flame." Curtly.
"It isn't that kind of fire."

The barbarians you remember are (human) Martians led by Czinczar. They invade Linn and kill the Lord Emperor Tews, but are defeated by Clane's superior technology. It turns out the Martians have invaded because Czinczar discovered aliens were planning to invade the Solar System.
There isn't a silver ball, but there is a mysterious ball of light that plays a minor part in the invasion story. It is left open ended what exactly the ball of light is.
The attack on the alien ship and the scene with the sculptor is not in the book, and I do not remember them from any of the van Vogt stories I have read. This doesn't prove anything since van Vogt wrote a lot of stories!

That's certainly the first part of my description. You may be right and I'm remembering more than one story. Thanks

Ah, I see the sequel  has the second part of my description. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Linn

@HaydonBerrow Aha, yes. I have that book but for some reason have never read it.

@John Rennie  When I saw the description I thought of Empire of the Atom.  So I up voted.
